# The difference in path lengths for waves in the double slit experiment

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, geometry, approximations

[image: Fig.1]

**Fig.1**

I don't quite understand the diagram, because it shows $L_1$ and $L_2$ as parallel, even though they are supposed to meet at the same point. I believe the idea is that $\Delta L$ approaches $d \sin \theta$ as the distance to the screen increases. However, that is not  exactly the case, and here is my proof:

[image]

**Fig.2**

I want to get a formula for $AF - BF$ in terms of $AF$, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, where these angles measure the angle between the horizontal gridlines and $AF$ and $BF$, respectively.

As we can see, we have dotted line that is parallel to $AF$, and a dotted line between them that is perpendicular to both of them. We have an even more finely dotted line $CD$ that is perpendicular to $BF$.

Now, first off, we can establish the following:

$$\begin{align} AF - BF &= AF - BC - CF \\ &= AF - BC - \sqrt{AF^2 + AC^2} \\ &=  AF - BC - \sqrt{AF^2 + \cos(\theta_1)^2d^2} \end{align} $$

So, now we must get another expression for $BC$. As we know from fig. 1 (using some trigonometry), $BE = d\sin(\theta_1)$. In fig. 2, we see that $BC = BE - DE$.

The angle between $BF$ and the dotted line is $\theta_2 - \theta_1$. Therefore, we have the following two identities:

$$CE= \sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1)\cdot BE = \sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1) d\sin(\theta_1)$$

$$CD = \sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1)\cdot BC$$

The line $DE$ can be given a new expression by the Pythagorean theorem:

$$DE = \sqrt{CE^2 -DC^2} = \sqrt{(\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1) d\sin(\theta_1))^2 - (\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1)\cdot BC)^2 }$$

As already established, $BC = BE - DC$. So, we have  the following expression for $BC$:

$$BC = d\sin(\theta_1)  - \sqrt{(\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1) d\sin(\theta_1))^2 - (\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1)\cdot BC)^2}  $$

Thus, we have our final expression for the difference:

$$AF - BF = AF - d\sin(\theta_1) + \sqrt{(\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1) d\sin(\theta_1))^2 - (\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1)\cdot BC)^2} - \sqrt{AF^2 + \cos(\theta_1)^2d^2} $$

Now, as the distance to the screen, denoted as $d_s$, increases relative to the distance between the slits, denoted as $d$, the difference in $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ decreases, which is fairly intuitive and simple to prove. Thusly, asking what $AF - BF$ approaches as  $d/d_s$ approaches zero is the sake as asking what $AF - BF$ approaches as $\theta_2 - \theta_1$ approaches zero. Thusly:

$$\begin{align} \lim_{\theta_2 - \theta_1 = 0} \Delta L &=  \lim_{\theta_2 - \theta_1 = 0}AF - BF \\[2ex] &= \lim_{\theta_2 - \theta_1 = 0}AF - d\sin(\theta_1) + \sqrt{(\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1) d\sin(\theta_1))^2 - (\sin(\theta_2 - \theta_1)\cdot BC)^2} - \sqrt{AF^2 + \cos(\theta_1)^2d^2} \\[2ex] &= AF - d\sin(\theta_1) - \sqrt{AF^2 + \cos(\theta_1)^2d^2} \end{align} $$

So, what gives? Is it just my trig that is off, or have I misunderstood what the diagram is trying to say to begin with?

Comment: For $d$ of 100 microns and $L$ of 5 meters, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Yeah, maybe like complete the square under the root, then take the square root, and try to expand in some small parameter....the approximation makes sense in the large $L/d$ limit, and I don't immediately see something wrong in your approach, so I think it's just massaging the last line.

Comment: Apply a binomial formula, binomial expansion, and you get $$AF-\sqrt{AF^2-\cos^2(\theta_1)d^2}=\frac{\cos^2(\theta_1)d^2}{AF+\sqrt{AF^2-\cos^2(\theta_1)d^2}},$$ so the whole limit expression is dominated by $-d\sin\theta_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R_b=\bar {BF}$ and $R_a=\bar {AF}$, and also the angle $\alpha =  \measuredangle [  \bar {AB}, \bar {BF}]$. Then using the Taylor exapansion of $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+\mathcal O(x^2)$ we get
$$R_a = \sqrt{R_b^2+d^2-2dR_b \cos(\alpha)} 
= R_b\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2}{R_b^2}-2\frac{d}{R_b} \cos(\alpha)}\\
=R_b\left(1-\frac{d}{R_b} \cos(\alpha) + \mathcal O \left(\frac{d^2}{R_b^2}\right)\right)$$
in other words, asymptotically the path difference $\delta L$ is
$$\delta L = R_b - R_a = d \cos(\alpha) + \mathcal O \left(\frac{d^2}{R_b^2}\right)$$
showing, to a 1st order error, that it is independent of the distance between the point of interference and the slit.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't quite understand the diagram, because it shows L1
> and L2
> as parallel, even though they are supposed to meet at the same point.

the interferences are located infinitely far from the slits, you need a lens so that the two rays can interfere